# PagingToolbar with JSON data - Ext JS

Tags: json, extjs

I'm trying to get a paging grid and toolbar working in my application.

Currently I have this Ajax request, which contains all my logic (making a request, decoding the response, creating a model/casting it to the store, and returning fields appropriately):

```
var request     = Ext.Ajax.request({
                url         : 'MCApp',
                jsonData    : searchquery, //String created from user input
                success     : function(response) {
                   var mainresponse     = response.responseText;   
                   var decoded          = Ext.decode( mainresponse );          
                   for( var i=0; i < decoded.elements.length; i++ ) {
                       var element      = decoded.elements[ i ].element;
                       var element_name = element.name;
                   var model = {};  
                   // loop over attributes
                   for( var x=0; x < element.attributes.length; x++ ) {
                       var attribute               = element.attributes[ x ];
                       model[ attribute.attrname ] = attribute.attrvalue;
                   }
                   // implicitly cast data as Model
                   newstore.add( model ); 
                   } //etc.
```

And my store:

```
var newstore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad    : true,
    pageSize    : 15,
    fields: [ 
        {name   : 'tech',   type    : 'auto'}, 
        {name   :'id',      type    : 'auto'}, 
        {name   :'name',    type    : 'auto'}
        //etc.
    ] 
});
```

I have an  `xtype: 'pagingtoolbar'` on my grid, using `store: newstore`, but it doesn't seem to read any data (i.e. "No items to display"):

```
var grid = Ext.define('AM.view.metadata.ResponseList' ,{
    extend  : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias   : 'widget.responselist',
    id      : 'reslist',
    //...
    dockedItems :[
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'bottom',
        items: [
            { xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',store: newstore, ...
```

Nowhere in my code do I define a proxy (perhaps that's an issue?) Anyhow, any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: What kind of proxy does the storeuse? Is that JSON? How are the rows added?  Do you add them manually, if yes, how?

Comment: I actually don't have any proxy specified, my request reads the URL and POSTs my jsonData to it, returning a response which I then decode. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: And the same `newstore` are used in your grid? It simply must be the same store in grid and pagingtoolbar.

Comment: Yes they are using the same store

Comment: That should work. Please create a simplified fiddle (using a button.onCLick() instead of making that POST request) to identify the exact problem.